# importing Source code into Jlist

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to importing a java source code into Jlst? Please tell me how, and ll appreciate an example if possible. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not I understand what you're trying to do, but can't you load your source file into a collection line-by-line (using [BufferedReader.readLine()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) around a [FileReader](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)), and then create the appropriate [ListModel](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ListModel.html) ?

I suspect a [TextArea](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html) may be more appropriate for code, though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to import it into JList. Text is better presented in JTextArea or JEditorPane. Here is where you can read more about it
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html